# Angular HTML Fields in Quill Editor with two way Binding

Tags: angular, quill

Does anyone have information on how I could include HTML  fields in Quill? I would like to have numeric fields inline with the text, and use two-way binding for Angular. Quill seems to remove my input fields when binding to the model.

```
 this.myValue = 5;
 this.myModelVar = "Here is a text box <input [(ngModel)]='myValue' name='myvalue' type='text'></input>
```

I'm open to just about anything, including creating additional observables, handling the communication in/out of the component myself, whatever I need to do.

However, at this point, I'm struggling just to get the input boxes to appear. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have not already done so, I would try using `[innerHTML]="myModelVar"` in your element that contains the content.

Comment: @cfoster5 I removed the [(ngModel)] binding, and tried using [innerHTML] to populate it, and it seems to replace the input fields in HTML with a dot. I'm going through the source code now to see what it's up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some ugly hack how to inject string including HTML tags into quill editor.

1. bind quill editor value to the new property [(ngModel)]="valueBind"
2. after binding use some event that occures before quill editor show (in my case 
   mat-tab-group:selectedIndexChange), and clone the original "value" property into "valueBind" property - now the quill editor shows the value correctly including HTML tags
3. before save action, copy "valueBind" property back to "value" property.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, on the project repository , the authors state that they dont I tend for quill to support html. Bummer, so I went to a different editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
<quill-editor name="quilleditor" [(ngModel)]="course.extraDescription"
                          [styles]="{'min-height': '120px'}">
</quill-editor>
```

Make sure you import { Forms } and provide the "name" attribute.
Hint: check the browser console.
Happy Debugging :)

Comment: Yes but the question is how to put an input box into extraDescription, which does it's own 2-way binding. Quill seems to strip out HTML.